# Set default ACL for new files and directories?

Tags: permissions, acl

I have two users ***usera*** and ***userb*** and a folder ***Both*** to which I am trying to set the ACL so that both users can create, update, delete any file or folder within that folder ***Both***. The problem is that if ***usera*** creates a folder ***User_A_Folder***, then ***userb*** is not allowed to delete this very folder. What ACL do I have to set recursively to the folder ***Both*** to give permission to both users to also delete files and folders that they haven't created by themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a user and its home (creates a group as well):

```
adduser Both
```

Add users to the new group:

```
usermod -a -G Both usera
usermod -a -G Both userb
```

Set the SETGID bit:

```
chmod g+s /home/Both
```

Allow group to write:

```
chmod g+w /home/Both
```

Set the access control list:

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /home/Both
```

Obviously creating a new user is optional but it does make life a little easier and clearer.

Comment: I'm investigating using ACLs to solve a problem and this showed up in a search result. I know this answer is 4+ years old, but this strikes me as curious. Why use setfacl in this case? Why not just combine the last three commands - and do away with setfacl - like so?: chmod g=rwxs /home/Both I get that you probably broke them out for explanatory reasons, so the main question is why the use of setfacl rather than chmod, thanks.

Comment: @jim the question was how to set the default ACL. Personally I find chmod only works where there are no actual users, just admins. For anything with 'users' I always use ACLs.